# case when sql server en una sola fila

Tags: sql-server

Hola como estan? queria saber si me pueden ayudar con esto.
yo tengo estas 3 tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

yo necesito traer los usuarios y los perfiles que tengan, como se muestra en la siguiente foto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los valores que me muestra estan bien, pero yo quiero que me genere una fila sola por usuario.

Les muestro la Query de como lo estoy haciendo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradezco si me pueden ayudar. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente necesitas usar una función de agregación (por ejemplo, `MAX`):

```
SELECT  u.IdUsuario,
        MAX(CASE WHEN pp.Id = 1 THEN 'Si' ELSE 'No' END) perfil1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN pp.Id = 2 THEN 'Si' ELSE 'No' END) perfil2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN pp.Id = 3 THEN 'Si' ELSE 'No' END) perfil3
FROM Usuario u
INNER JOIN PerfilUsuario pu
    ON u.idUsuario = pu.idUsuario
INNER JOIN Perfil pp
    ON pu.PerfilId = pp.Id
GROUP BY u.IdUsuario
;
```